# The password retrieval answer provided is invalid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a unit test for creating a new user . When i fill up the desired fields it gives me error "the password retrieval answer provided is invalid"

Here is my Form
[image]

Here is my code

```
        public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            _provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, string.Empty, string.Empty, true, string.Empty, out status);
            return status;
        }

        public bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = _provider.GetUser(userName, true /* userIsOnline */);
            return currentUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kanwar singh kuch samj me aye aisa question pucho

Comment: @kanwar singh don't copy & paste the whole controller's code.
Just ask for the main problem.

Comment: Thanks neel and rahul now i have reduce the code and the only method in which error has occured. so now please try to resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set all parameters in CreateUser() method.